# Json-c sample program compilation

Tags: c, json, fedora

I am trying to execute a sample c structure program in json-c. I have installed json-c using git clone. How i can compile my c program. What all changes i have to make in Makefile ? 
Or is there any other method to execute programs in json-c.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the `json-c`that you can clone from https://github.com/json-c/json-c.git the wiki at https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki tells you what you need to do:

```
To setup JSON-C to build on your system please run:
./configure --prefix=/some/install/path
make
make check
make install
```